# Getting Error while clip raster using shape file

Tags: python, geopandas, coordinate-transformation, geotiff, rasterio

```
# Read Shapefile
with fiona.open("/content/drive/My Drive/shapefile/shape_files/lidar_shape.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

# read imagery file
with rasterio.open("/content/drive/My Drive/shapefile/imagery_trans.tif") as src:
    out_image,out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta

# Save clipped imagery
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("/content/drive/My Drive/shapefile/imagery_trans_clip.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

I am trying to clip the raster file with the shapefile file. both files have the same coordinates system. This  is my code and I am getting the error ( TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Affine')

errors occurred to this line :- out_image,out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the CRS of the shapefile is different from that of the raster.